# Remove primary key in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, datatable

is there a way to remove primary key from the datatable Or is there any way to remove the constraints of "PK" first and then remove the column itself?

Thanks!

UPDATED:

```
 dtTable.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("PRIMARY_KEY", typeof(System.Int32)));
 dtTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[1] { dtTable.Columns["PRIMARY_KEY"] }; // throws an error
 dtTable.Columns["PRIMARY_KEY"].AutoIncrement = true;
```

Comment: Which database? Please consider your tags.

Comment: i have mention datatable in the question. Which means the asp.net datatable

Comment: .NET's System.Data.DataTable, because it doesn't belongs solely to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can remove primay key using

```
DataTable.PrimaryKey = null;
```

you can delete data table column using

```
DataTable.Columns.Remove("column name here");
```

Comment: would this remove column or the constraint? If later, then how to remove column?

Comment: thanks! that works! But if i am adding it again (i need that way!) it is threwing an error of "These columns don't currently have unique values". I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: @Xor power: So... *do* these columns currently have unique values?

Comment: @Xor power: Well, if you remove the column, the values are gone. And if you re-add the column later, it contains the default value (which is not unique).

Answer (score 2):

I found that sometimes after removing PrimaryKey from a DataTable:

```
MyDataTable.PrimaryKey = null;
```

the Unique setting remains true on the member columns of the deleted PrimaryKey.

My solution:

```
 public static void KillPrimaryKey(DataTable LocDataTable)
{
  int LocPriKeyCount = LocDataTable.PrimaryKey.Length;
  string[] PrevPriColumns = new string[LocPriKeyCount];

  // 1. Store ColumnNames in a string Array
  for (int ii = 0; ii < LocPriKeyCount; ii++) PrevPriColumns[ii] = LocDataTable.PrimaryKey[ii].ColumnName;
  // 2. Clear PrimaryKey
  LocDataTable.PrimaryKey = null;
  // 3. Clear Unique settings
  for (int ii = 0; ii < LocPriKeyCount; ii++) LocDataTable.Columns[PrevPriColumns[ii]].Unique = false;
}
```

Comment: why this long code? why not using foreach as 'foreach(DataColumn dac in LocDataTable.Columns)dac.Unique = false;'